# How to properly implement many to one structure in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know this is an age old question but i just cant get it working and would love a human explanation!

I have four tables in my database and would like to only make one api call to get the data out - the tables represent different entities, books, articles, cases and statutes, i would like a model called bibliography which pulls all this together.

I have tried the following, but after adding data to the tables and calling this one's controller, i get a 200 ok with [0] data.

**My models:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PhDResourceManager.Models
{
    public class Journal
    {
        public Journal() { }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string PublicationYear { get; set; }
        public string PublicationName { get; set; }
        public string PageNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Bibliography Bibliography { get; set; }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public Book() { }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Edition { get; set; }
        public string PublicationYear { get; set; }
        public string PublisherName { get; set; }
        public string PageNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Bibliography Bibliography { get; set; }
    }

    public class Case
    {
        public Case() { }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Parties { get; set; }
        public string NeutralCitation { get; set; }
        public string LawReportsCitation { get; set; }
        public virtual Bibliography Bibliography { get; set; }
    }

    public class Statute
    {
        public Statute() { }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public virtual Bibliography Bibliography { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bibliography
    {
        public Bibliography()
        {
            MyJournals = new List<Journal>();
            MyCases = new List<Case>();
            MyBooks = new List<Book>();
            MyStatutes = new List<Statute>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Journal> MyJournals { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Case> MyCases { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Book> MyBooks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Statute> MyStatutes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My controller:**

```
namespace PhDResourceManager.Controllers
{
    public class BibliographyController : ApiController
    {
        private PhDResourceManagerContext db = new PhDResourceManagerContext();

        // GET: api/Bibliography
        public IQueryable<Bibliography> GetBibliographies()
        {
            return db.Bibliographies;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool BibliographyExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Bibliographies.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your controller action code ?

Comment: Looks like you simply need to `Incude()` the collections.

Comment: How would i do that Gert?

Comment: db.Bibliographies.Include(b => b.MyJournals).Include(b => b.MyCases).Include(b => b.MyBooks).Include(b => b.MyStatutes); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: Changed the get method to public Bibliography GetBibliographies()
        {
                Bibliography bibliography = new Bibliography();
                bibliography.MyJournals = db.Journal.ToList();
                bibliography.MyCases = db.Cases.ToList();
                bibliography.MyBooks = db.Books.ToList();
                bibliography.MyStatutes = db.Statutes.ToList();
                return bibliography;
        }

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Changed method to the following:

```
 public Bibliography GetBibliographies()
        {
                Bibliography bibliography = new Bibliography();
                bibliography.MyJournals = db.Journal.ToList();
                bibliography.MyCases = db.Cases.ToList();
                bibliography.MyBooks = db.Books.ToList();
                bibliography.MyStatutes = db.Statutes.ToList();
                return bibliography;
        }
```

Comment: That gets you an entity with a bunch of unrelated collections, in fact all the data from all the tables. If you are looking for something like that, build a ViewModel with a property for each collection. A Bibliography ENTITY model should only contain a specific entity and its related entities. Use the Include() syntax for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have just used .Include() like others suggested. If your tables have appropriate relationships they would come down with your GetBibliographies api.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx